# Counting Records/Rows

Tags: vba, excel, count, countif

I have a macro that saves an excel file down to .txt. I need to insert a record count to the top of the .txt file ("Records|123"). I have the row inserted, I have the word Records in A1, now I'm trying to figure out how to get a row count in B1. I've tried CountIf, LastRow, EndRow and now COUNT. I'm subtracting 2 because row 1 is the record count and row 2 is column headers, and I'm referencing column D because columns A-C contain numbers and it didn't like that either. Here is what I have:

```
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Records"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.Value = (EndRow - 2)
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNT(D:D)"
```

This is giving me Records|0. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work? Or can you point me in a different direction? Thank you in advance.

Comment: COUNT gives the total cells containing numbers. Perhaps you want COUNTA?

Comment: [Avoid using `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long

ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

With ws
    .Range("B1") = lr - 2
End with
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have just gotten a row count before you inserted the header row.

```
dim newvariable as long
newvariable = Thisworkbook.worksheets("yoursheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

And then insert your new header row and place that value in the cell like:

```
Thisworkbook.worksheets("yoursheet").Range("a1").Value = newvariable
```